# How to programmatically force marking a RowSelection in webplayer Spotfire DataTable

Tags: c#, spotfire

How to programmatically force marking of a RowSelection of DataTable in spotfire, So when end-user open a template in webplayer, the specified rows must be selected and marked?
I tried using below code, but it does not force marking selection:

```
 // If document properties specified, update them if exist
    DataManager dataManager = application.GetService<DataManager>();

 // Mark database row before we refresh the data tables
    RowSelection allRows = dataManager.AllRows.GetSelection(table);
    application.Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference.SetSelection(allRows, table);
```

When open, I want it like below:
[image]

But it show like below:
[image]

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily accomplished using the following steps:

- Marking everything you want marked (as you want the user to see it)
- Go to Edit > Document Properties > Library and uncheck the "Remember personalized view for each Web Player User
- Save the DXP to the Library.

Now when ever a user opens this dxp, they will see it in the sate in which you saved it.

Comment: Referring to your first point we should mark the rows from the template itself ! But what I want is to achieve the mark programmatically. Do you have any further suggestion?

Comment: Then you can use ironpython... but this really makes no sense for your use case. http://www.bearonspotfire.com/mark-rows-and-unmark-rows-using-scripts-in-spotfire

Comment: I think @BasharAbuShamaa can help by detailing the use case a bit better :)

Comment: I got over "Document Properties" and unchecked the "Remember..."; But it still, the row is not marked when open the Document from library !!

Comment: Many thanks @scsimon , I found the error was in js code that it do reset all marks analysisDocument.marking.setMarking(names[i], dt[j].dataTableName, "", spotfire.webPlayer.markingOperation.CLEAR);

Comment: @scsimon Do you know any way to speed up (optimize) open spotfire analysis document? It takes too long period!

Comment: The speed on opening relies on the data associated with it. I'm guessing you have a ton of data so that's just life. It's hardware limitations at the data source or on your application server.